# Ruby/Rails inheritance, overriding validators defined in super-class in sub-class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, paperclip, paperclip-validation

I have the following rails/paperclip validator:

```
class ImageRatioValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    attr_name = "#{attribute}_width".to_sym
    value = record.send(:read_attribute_for_validation, attribute)
    valid_ratios = options[:ratio]

    if !value.queued_for_write[:original].blank?
      geo = Paperclip::Geometry.from_file value.queued_for_write[:original]

      # first we need to validate the ratio
      cur_ratio = nil
      valid_ratios.each do |ratio, max_width|
        parts = ratio.split ":"
        next unless (geo.height * parts.first.to_f) == (geo.width * parts.last.to_f)
        cur_ratio = ratio
      end
      # then we need to make sure the maximum width of the ratio is honoured
      if cur_ratio
        if not valid_ratios[cur_ratio].to_f >= geo.width
          record.errors[attribute] << "The maximum width for ratio #{cur_ratio} is #{valid_ratios[cur_ratio]}. Given width was #{geo.width}!"
        end
      else
        record.errors[attribute] << "Please make sure you upload a stall logo with a valid ratio (#{valid_ratios.keys.join(", ")})!"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

the validator is used in both super (super-class is not abstract so can be instanciated) and sub-class. In the sub-class I need to change the ratios allowed:

Super-class:

```
class Superclass
    validates_attachment :logo, :image_ratio => { :ratio  => {"1:1" => "28", "4:1" => "50", "5:1" => "40"} }
end
```

Sub-class:

```
class Subclass < Superclass
  validates_attachment :logo, :image_ratio => { :ratio  => {"1:1" => "40", "2:1" => "60"} }
end
```

The validator works as expected in the super-class however seems to ignore the new ratios given in the sub-class.
Am I trying to use the validators in a non Rails way? How should I be using the validators in a situation like the one described above?

Answer (score 0):

When you inherit from the superclass you also get the validators from it. I'm not 100% sure of this but I think that you just add your new validators to the list of old ones, ie both constrains apply.

I think the easiest solution is to put common logic in a module or inherit from a common superclass. You could also do something like this, but I think it's pretty ugly:

```
class Superclass
    with_options :unless => Proc.new { |a| a.validators.any? } do |super_validators|
        super_validators.validates :password, :length => { :minimum => 10 }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't ideal as a solution, but fairly clean.

Just use custom validation based on the type. This way you will have both validators defined in the super class, but it will definitely work.

```
class Superclass
    validates_attachment :logo, :image_ratio => { :ratio  => {"1:1" => "28", "4:1" => "50", "5:1" => "40"} }, :if => self.is_a?(SuperClass)
    validates_attachment :logo, :image_ratio => { :ratio  => {"1:1" => "40", "2:1" => "60"} }, :if => self.is_a?(SubClass)
end
```